# Delete , Add, Edit stringList

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

This is a bit confusing but will try best to explain it. please ask if you need more details.

First i have a class called `TPlayers` Like so..

```
TPlayers = class
   Private
      p : array[1..20] of TStringList;
      function GetPlayer(i:integer): TStringList;

    Public
      Property player[i : integer] : TStringList read GetPlayer;

           constructor Create;   virtual;
    implementation

    uses
    main;
    {constructor}
       constructor TPlayers.Create;
       begin
         p[1] := TStringList.Create;
         p[2] := TStringList.Create;
         p[3] := TStringList.Create;
         p[4] := TStringList.Create;
         p[5] := TStringList.Create;
         p[6] := TStringList.Create;
       end;

     function TPlayers.GetPlayer(i: integer): TStringList;
    begin
      Result := p[i];
    end;
```

I now have `FTherePlayers := TPlayers.Create` to create the class. 
First time i add to the stringlist like so

```
FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(name2)].Add('posx='+inttostr(posL.x));
```

or with variables taken out

```
FTherePlayers.Player[1].Add('posx=15');
```

This seems to be fine, but next i try to update it like so

```
FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(ID)].Values['posx='] := xpos;
```

or with variables taken out

```
FTherePlayers.Player[1].Values['posx='] := 12;
```

but then i check that value after changing it and it still says 15, thus when i do

```
showmessage(fthereplayers.player[1].Values['posx']);
```

it returns 15 but it should be 12.  Any idea why its not changeing?
thanks
Glen

Comment: You have a typo in `FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(ID)].Values['posx='] := xpos;`, it should be `FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(ID)].Values['posx'] := xpos;` instead. But it's not a good idea to expose those string lists, rather create method for adding, like `TPlayers.AddPlayer` and indexed property e.g. `TPlayers.PlayerPosition[x]`, which will access the `Values` of the internal string list.

Comment: arg, how did i not see that.  also thanks, i all ready have an addplayer but i figured the FTherePlayers.Player[x] was only accessed by the private get player and .p[x] thus ok, but adding a player position which will access the values would not be hard to do , just did not see the point..but again i am still kind of new to delphi and its common constructor

Comment: If you use above delphi2010 then look add the Generics.Collections. TList, TObjectList, TDictionary and TObjectDictionary

Comment: the typo was the answer if you want to make it an answer ill accept it. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra equals sign at the end of the `Name` index value of the [`Values`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Values) property. You need to use only the name portion of a name value pair without the equals sign. So, in your code just replace the following lines:

```
// here is an extra equals sign in 'posx=' index value
FTherePlayers.Player[1].Values['posx='] := 12;
FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(ID)].Values['posx='] := xpos;
```

with this:

```
FTherePlayers.Player[1].Values['posx'] := 12; 
FTherePlayers.Player[strtoint(ID)].Values['posx'] := xpos;
```